# Nested Scorll Problem in React native using nested FlatList

Tags: react-native, scrollview, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

`The problem here is the nested scroll View.
In the UI there is a parent  Flat list  as a vertical, inside it child flat list with a Horizontal and then there is one scrollView with a Horizontal

what we are expecting, we are unable to Scroll the inner Scroll View, every time the Flatlist with the Horizontal will scroll.

I have tried to implement the Flatist instead of the inner Scroll View!
still, it didn't work! also used react-native-gesture-handler but the issue persisted.

Following is the code for FlatList :`

```
  <FlatList data={Object.entries(ExpData)}
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                nestedScrollEnabled
                renderItem={({ item }: any) => {
                    let key = item[0];
                    let val = item[1];
                    let mealId = item[1][0].meal_category_id;
                    return <View>
                        <View style={styles.expContainerHeader}>
                            <Text style={styles.nearByHeaderText}> {key} </Text>
                            <TouchableOpacity style={{ flexDirection: "row" }} 
           onPress={() => handleSeeAll(mealId, key)}>
                                <Text style={styles.seeAllText}>See All</Text>
                                <Image
                                    source={IMG_CONST.seeAll}
                                    style={styles.seeAll}
                                    testID="seeAllIconId"
                                />
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                        <FlatList data={val}
                            horizontal
                            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                            nestedScrollEnabled
                            renderItem={({ item }: any) => {
                                let id = item.id;
                                const CurrencyPriceIndicator =
                      (priceindicator: any, currency: any) => {
                                    let currencysymbol = '';

                                    if (priceindicator == 1) {
                                        currencysymbol = `${currency}`;
                                    } else if (priceindicator == 2) {
                                        currencysymbol = `${currency}${currency}`;
                                    } else if (priceindicator == 3) {
                                        currencysymbol = `${currency}${currency}${currency}`;
                                    }

                                    return currencysymbol;
                                }
                                return (
                                    <View style={styles.expCardContaioner} key={Date()}>
                                        <ScrollView horizontal={true}
                          style={styles.expImgContainer} 
                       showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
                                            {item?.images?.map((elem: any) => {
                                                return (
                                                    <TouchableOpacity
                             key={elem.id} onPress={() => handleImagePress(id)}>
                                                        <Image
                                                            source={{ uri: elem.url }}
                                                            style={styles.images}
                                                            testID="locationIconId"
                                                        />
                                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                                );
                                            })}
                                        </ScrollView>
                                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.expTitleView}
                          onPress={() => handleViewExpCard(id)}>
                                            <Text style={styles.expTitleText}>
                           {item.title} </Text>
                                            <Text style={styles.mealTypeTitle}>
                      {item.meal_type} •
                       {CurrencyPriceIndicator(item.price_indecator, currency)}</Text>
                                            <View style={styles.ratingContainer}>
                                                <Rating
                                                    readonly={true}
                                                    type='custom'
                                                    ratingImage={IMG_CONST.STAR}
                                                    ratingColor='#F59E0B'
                                                    ratingBackgroundColor='#CBD5E1'
                                                    ratingCount={5}
                                                    startingValue={item.average_rating}
                                                    imageSize={25}
                                                    fractions={2}
                                                    style={{ paddingVertical: 1 }}
                                                />
                                                <Text style={styles.rate}>
                                                    {item.average_rating} ({item.total_reviews})
                                                </Text>
                                            </View>
                                            <View 
                      style={{ flexDirection: 'row', marginBottom: wp(4) }}>

                                                <Image
                                                    source={IMG_CONST.location}
                                                    style={styles.locationIcon}
                                                    testID="locationIconId"
                                                />
                                                <Text style={styles.rate}>
                                                    {item.city_name} 
                       {location ? `• ${milesToKilometers(item.distance, currency)}`: null}
                                                </Text>
                                            </View>
                                        </TouchableOpacity>
                                    </View>
                                )
                            }} />
                    </View>
                }}
            />
```

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
seeAll: {
marginLeft: wp(1),
alignSelf: 'center',
height: wp(2.5),
width: wp(2),
},
images: {
height: hp(15), width: hp(15),
marginEnd: wp(2),
borderRadius: 20
},
locationIcon: {
height: wp(5),
width: wp(5),
},
rate: {
color: '#000',
marginLeft: wp(2)
},
ratingContainer: {
flexDirection: 'row',
alignItems: "center",
paddingVertical: hp(1.2)
},
mealTypeTitle: {
marginTop: wp(2.5),
color: '#000',
fontWeight: "500",
fontSize: Scale(16)
},
expTitleView: {
marginLeft: wp(3),
},
expTitleText: {
color: '#000',
fontWeight: '700',
fontSize: Scale(20),
},
expImgContainer: {
marginTop: wp(3),
marginLeft: wp(3),
marginBottom: wp(3),
zIndex: 99
},
expImgs: {
backgroundColor: 'red',
height: hp(15),
width: hp(15),
borderRadius: Scale(20)
},
expCardContaioner: {
marginTop: wp(2),
marginRight: wp(3),
backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
paddingVertical: wp(1),
borderRadius: Scale(20),
marginBottom: wp(3),
width: width - Scale(50),
},
expContainer: {
margin: wp(5),
marginTop: wp(1.5)
},

```
    nearByHeaderText: {
        fontSize: Scale(16),
        fontWeight: "500",
        color: "#120d26"
    },
    seeAllText: {
        fontSize: Scale(16),
        fontWeight: "500",
        color: "#747688"
    },
    expContainerHeader: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        margin: wp(1)
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using nested Flatlist is not a good solution at all. There are several built-in props inside `Flatlist` like `ListHeaderComponent` and `ListFooterComponent` we can pass our custom component inside it. And inside our component we can use a `Flatlist` as well.

Here is an example where you can use `Vertical` and `Horizontal` scroll at the same time.

```js
const YourComponent = () => {
  //// & flatlist function for Order list ///

  const renderItemFunction = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <YourCustomeComponet
        title={item.clientName}
        status={item.status}
        date={item.date}
        document={item.numDocuments}
        billStatus={item.paymentStatus}
        userName={item.agentName}
      />
    );
  };

  //// & flatlist HeaderComponent function///

  const listHeaderComponent = () => {
    return (
      <>
        <FlatList
          data={StatusData}
          ref={flatListRef}
          horizontal={true}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          horizontal={true}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          renderItem={renderItemList}
        />
      </>
    );
  };
  // const listFooterComponent = () => {
  //   return (
  //     <>
  //       <FlatList
  //         data={StatusData}
  //         ref={flatListRef}
  //         horizontal={true}
  //         keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
  //         horizontal={true}
  //         showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  //         renderItem={renderItemList}
  //       />
  //     </>
  //   );
  // };
  return (
    <>
      <FlatList
        ListHeaderComponent={listHeaderComponent}
        ListHeaderComponentStyle={styles.headerComponent}
        data={yourData}
        contentContainerStyle={{ alignItems: "center" }}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        renderItem={renderItemFunction}
        // You can use ListFooterComponent as well
        // ListFooterComponent={listFooterComponent}
        // ListFooterComponentStyle={styles.footerComponent}
      />
    </>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  headerComponent: {},
});
export default YourComponent;
```

Comment: Appreciate for the Answer but can you tell me how Horizontal works in Horizontal FlatList !?

Comment: Do you mean the behavior of a single FlatList in  Horizontal? if yes the see this: https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#horizontal

Comment: Ok, I am aware of this reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#horizontal, suppose if i want to implement this ,   <FlatList 
                                horizontal
                                ...
                             renderItem={({ item }: any) => {
                                 return (
                              <FlatList 
                                horizontal
                                ... 
                                />
                                             )
                              }/>